# How to combine data and show image in angular datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, datatable, angular-datatables

I am using [angular datatable](https://github.com/l-lin/angular-datatables) to create tables and following is my working plnkr - http://plnkr.co/edit/pQ0TrNEjzyXmvFcIvkSr?p=preview

Here I want to merge two column data to one, i.e. to show Address 1 & Address 2 as Address something like - addr1 - addr2 and also (2) to show image in table column instead of link.

I tried -

`DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('addr1' - 'addr2').withTitle('Address 1'),` and `DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('addr1 - addr2')` but no luck(throwing error)

Please help me with this. Thanks.

**My Script -**

```
var dd = [];
dd = [
    {"Img": "http://img.banggood.com/thumb/other_items/upload/2012/liangping/animal%20head%20masks-011%20(4).jpg", "Name": "Tiger Nixon", "Age": "61", "addr1": "234 My addr 1", "addr2": "234 My addr 2"},
    {"Img": "http://a.deviantart.net/avatars/a/n/animal-animes.png", "Name": "Garrett Winters","Age": "63", "addr1": "235 My addr 1", "addr2": "235 My addr 2"}
  ];   

  $scope.dtColumns = [
    DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('addr1').withTitle('Address 1'),
    DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('addr2').withTitle('Address 2'),
    DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('Img').withTitle('Image'),
    DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('Name').withTitle('Name'),
    DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('Age').withTitle('Age')
  ];

  $scope.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.newOptions()
    .withOption('data', dd);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use renderWith on your column [angular-datatable documentation](http://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/bindAngularDirective)

```
$scope.dtColumns = [
    DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('addr1').withTitle('Address 1'),
    DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('addr2').withTitle('Address 2'),
    DTColumnBuilder.newColumn(null).withTitle('Full Address').renderWith(addressHtml),
    DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('Img').withTitle('Image'),
    DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('Name').withTitle('Name'),
    DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('Age').withTitle('Age')
];

$scope.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.newOptions()
    .withOption('data', dd);

function addressHtml(data, type, full, meta) {
        return data.addr1 + ' - ' + data.addr2;
}
```

the updated plunker : http://plnkr.co/edit/T2XMUFxORSy3z7dDgRcc?p=preview

You can add image if you need ...