# Set fontawesome icon DTColumnBuilder in Datatable in Angular Js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-datatables

I am displaying Json data into datatable using DTColumnBuilder. So right now I am able to display data into each row of the column. But I want to set one font-awesome icon in each row in column.

**Controller:**

```
angular.module('app.example').controller('xyz', function ($scope,$http,$state, $stateParams,Rh,DTOptionsBuilder,DTColumnBuilder,DTColumnDefBuilder) {

  this.standardOptions = DTOptionsBuilder

  .fromFnPromise(Rl.all('abc/main/logic').getList())
  //Add Bootstrap compatibility
  .withDOM("<'dt-toolbar'<'col-xs-12 col-sm-6'f><'col-sm-6 col-xs-12 hidden-xs'l>r>" +
  "t" +
  "<'dt-toolbar-footer'<'col-sm-6 col-xs-12 hidden-xs'i><'col-xs-12 col-sm-6'p>>")
  .withBootstrap();
  this.standardColumns = [
    DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('msg.firstName'),
    DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('msg.lastName'),   

  ];

});
```

**HTML**

```
<table datatable dt-options="datatables.standardOptions" dt-columns="datatables.standardColumns" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>                    
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

I want to add font-awesome icon in column.

```
DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('fontawesome-icon'),
<th>Action</th>
```

I have seen one link but I am not getting it correctly. [How to combine data and show image in angular datatable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33053739/how-to-combine-data-and-show-image-in-angular-datatable). Because I want to use only font-awesome.

```
<i class="fa fa-refresh" aria-hidden="true"></i>
```

I have one function for this But I am not able call this function

```
function action(data) {  
  return $sce.trustAsHtml('<i class="fa fa-fw fa-folder-open-o"> </i>');
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `renderWith` :

```
DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('msg.lastName')
  .renderWith(function(data, type, full, meta) {
     return '<i class="fa fa-refresh" aria-hidden="true"></i>'
   })
```

HTML will be rendered. See https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render for details.

example -> **http://plnkr.co/edit/NZSFrdeCAObbRjCAa7Vi?p=preview**

---

Use `createdCell` and `$compile` if you need to attach directives to the returned HTML :

```
.withOption('createdCell', function(cell, cellData, rowData, rowIndex, colIndex) {
   $compile(cell)($scope)
})
```

Comment: I  putted ng-click on the  return data + '&nbsp' + '<i class="fa fa-refresh" aria-hidden="true"></i>'. But ng-click is not working.

Comment: No, because angular not is aware of the rendered markup. See update, have updated the plnkr as well.